# Making a change program for my java class, not sure how to get total number of coins

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm currently making a program for my class that tells you your amount of change when you type a number. I got all of that down, but at the end it wants me to put the total number of coins. For example, if I type 96 into the program it'll tell me that's 3 quarters, 2 dimes, 0 nickels, and 1 pennies. Obviously, the total number of coins is 6, but how do I get it to tell me that? Here's my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class MakeChange {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


//get total number of cents from user
System.out.println("Enter total number of cents:");
int change = keyboard.nextInt();



//TODO: get input


System.out.println("Exact change is:");
int quarters = change / 25;
change = change % 25;
int dimes = change / 10;
change = change % 10;
int nickels = change / 5;
change = change % 5;
int pennies = change / 1;
System.out.println(quarters + " quarters");
System.out.println(dimes + " dimes");
System.out.println(nickels + " nickels");
System.out.println(pennies + " pennies");
System.out.println(" Total number of coins is:");
//TODO: calculate and output number of each coin to make change for given input total
//TODO: calculate and output total number of coins
```

}
}

Comment: I believe you are looking for the [`+` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).  Just add all the different types of coins together.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to add up all of your coins counts, which you conveniently placed in separate variables.

Here is how you could to:

```
System.out.println(quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies);
```

As [@Charlie Armstrong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13623742/charlie-armstrong) pointed out in the comments, you should see [Arithmetic Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)